# Difficulties in understanding simple Android ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

After doing some search, i found out how to make adapter and view some string data in listview and add event listeners. This is the code,

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    private MediaPlayer player = null; 
    ListView listV;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_result);
        listV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);


         String[] values = new String[] { "C 2 F", "F 2 C", "Currency"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.listView1, values);

         listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

         listV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              int itemPosition     = position;

              if(itemPosition == 1)
              {
                i.putExtra("identify", "c2f");
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                if(player != null)
                    player.stop();
              }
              else if(itemPosition == 2)
              {
                  i.putExtra("identify", "f2c");
                  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                  if(player != null)
                      player.stop();
              }
              else if(itemPosition == 3)
              {
                  i.putExtra("identify", "currency");
                  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                  if(player != null)
                      player.stop();
              }


             }

        }); 
    }
```

When i launch the app, it crashes, showing NullPointerException on line "ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.listView1, values);" I guess its because of android.R.layout.activity_list_item, in the example i saw, this was android.R.layout.activity_list_item_1, i dont know where to define it or whats the purpose of this, and kindly elaborate the process of filling up the listview and why is it so complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

Looking at the source @

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/activity_list_item.xml?av=f

I don't think you need `android.R.layout.activity_list_item`

Also you may want to look at the constructors of `ArrayAdapter`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: That worked. Now can you please tell me how to set different properties of this textViwe? like, text gravity, color, size etc..

Comment: @AbdulJabbar you can't coz you have not defined a custom layout. To do that instead of using built in layout form the framework you will need to use a custom layout with a textview in it

Answer (score 2):

I guess those two arguments are the problem:

- android.R.layout.activity_list_item:

  This is the layout xml that is used for the rows.
- The second id (you used `R.id.listView1`):

  This is the id of the `TextView` in the layout you passed before that will be filled with the data. It must be a `TextView` in the above specified layout, so `R.id.listView1` will likely not work.

Answer (score 1):

remove this `R.id.listView1 it should be

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,  values);
listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```